# Rename mulitple special characters in filenames

Tags: python-3.x

I always have problems with special characters and Ä, Ö, Ü in the filenames of files. So far I have collected and replaced the characters. But there are always new ones and it is simply not automated

e.g filenames:

```
testç.txt
aaaä.txt
gggggggç.txt
rrérr.txt
-Î¥tr.pdf
```

e.g. here:

```
def rename():
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('ç', 'c')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('ä', 'ae')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('ç', 'c')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('ä', 'ae')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('Ä', 'ae')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('Ö', 'oe')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('ö', 'oe')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('Ü', 'ue')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    [os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, f).replace('ü', 'ue')) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    etc....
```

Is there a simple possibility to replace all special characters and and Ä, Ö, Ü in all files in the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unicodedata` module

**Ex:**

```
import unicodedata
os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), os.path.join(dirpath, unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', f).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())) for f in os.listdir(dirpath)]
```

**Demo:**

```
import unicodedata
s = ['testç.txt', 'aaaä.txt', 'gggggggç.txt', 'rrérr.txt', '-Î¥tr.pdf']

for i in s:
    print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', i).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())
```

**Output:**

```
testc.txt
aaaa.txt    
gggggggc.txt
rrerr.txt   
-Itr.pdf
```

Comment: this is exactly where i was looking for. I replaced ä, ö, ü correctly manually. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The module `unicodedata` gives you some internal list of changes. But, as far as I can see, some of the changes are not that you want. For example `ä` will be changed with `a`, not with `ae`, etc. Perhaps it can be tweaked somehow, I don't know.

So if you prefer to stick to your personal change list you sill need to write down the list explicitly but your code can be much shorter at least:

```
from pathlib import Path

changes = {"ä":"ae", "ö":"oe", "ç":"c", "ü":"u", "é":"e", "î":"i"} # etc

folder = Path.cwd() / "files"       # subfolder with files in current folder
files  = Path.glob(folder, "*")     # get all files from the subfolder

def replace(name):
    name = name.lower()             # convert all to lower case: ÄÖ --> äö
    for char in name:
        if char in changes:
            name = name.replace(char, changes[char])
    return name

for f in files:
    new_name = replace(f.name)
    print(f"{f.name :20} --> {new_name}")
    f.rename(folder/new_name)
```

Output:

```
...\files\

-Î¥tr.pdf            --> -i¥tr.pdf
aaaä.txt             --> aaaae.txt
gügggÖggüügç.txt     --> gugggoegguugc.txt
rrérr.txt            --> rrerr.txt
testç.txt            --> testc.txt
```

And your list can be about two times shorter if you will convert the filenames in lower case. You won't need to make two replaces `Ö --> oe` and `ö --> oe`, etc.